# How to Debug on Exception handled by a specific Try-Catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging

While not exclusive to this situation, suppose you have a tool you use, which exposes its API by calling code that you provide. Such as [Gulp](https://gulpjs.com), for instance.

As it does its work, the library will enclose it's pipeline, very early, in something like...

```
try { 
    library.doSomethingWith( input )
} 
catch(err){ 
    throw library.prettify(err) 
}
```

When "internal" errors do hit (often caused in [user-land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_space)), it may help, rethrowing some potentially more legible error to console. However, if I decide I would like to step through the error in Chrome DevTools or preferred debugging interface, I can't do that. This is because the particular error I care about has "collapsed" into `err` and the `Error{}` re-thrown has it's own, useless, live stack-trace.

In some situations this is ok because you can simply break on **all** exceptions. However there is a major drawback when using libraries complex enough to have asynchronous behavior. As far as I know, you cannot filter out procedural errors which certain libraries and even the node runtime will `throw` and `catch` by rote, **literally per-tick**.

More often than not, when I pause on caught exceptions, I will persistently hit some variant of

```
try {
    throw new Error()
} catch {
    //transcend annoyance
}
```

buried deeply in a core dependency.

So with all that said, are there ways to *intercept* a `catch` before the error is consumed? While I figure such a feature wouldn't be readily available in the major debuggers, are there commands in the Node Debugger API or special techniques to effectively do one of the following?

- pause before the runtime steps out of a try-block, into catch statement
- pause directly on exceptions that *will* be caught by a debugger-marked `try {}`
- regenerate debugging state of an original error, within its respective `catch` block
- "pause on all exceptions" except those outside marked context, or inside blacklisted files

It would be a major boost for moral and productivity if errors could be targeted in any of these ways.

Comment: While I don't consider it integral to this question, it is Babel, with which I am facing this issue, as I debug and test my own transforms

Answer (score 3):

You must be knowing this but anyway,

You can use following option to break the execution whenever some error occurs.

[image]